# Typescript: access this from class scope and this from function scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, scope, onclick

I have a svg component with a click listener:

```
export class test {
    param: any;

    //...
    .on("click", () => {
        this.param = this.__data__;
    });
}
```

I would like to access param from the class test (which works the way above) and access `this.__data__` from the scope of the click context...
I've tried to define `self = this` in the class, and other things, but can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think that you need to use a fat function:

```
let self = this;
.on("click", function() {
  self.param = this.__data__;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [the valid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38352300/3786294) of Thierry Templier here, perhaps you could use an `event.currentTarget`:

```
el.on("click", (evt) => {
    this.param = evt.currentTarget.__data__;
});
```

I don't know who provides the `el` in your example. But `currentTarget` exists [in DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) and [in JQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).